# regex expression to include optional decimals

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a python script using regex that will take a string such as this one:

```
string = "C:66:66:0:0%:1E0 C:18:18:0:0%:1E0 C:26:26:0:0%:1E0 C:95:95:0:0%:1E0 Y:106:104:2:1.89%:2.4882E-1
```

and break it up into chunks such as this

```
C:66:66:0:0%:1E0
```

The code I have right now is:

```
res = re.findall("\w+:\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+%:\w+", string)
```

but the output leaves out everything following the "Y" due to the decimals

```
['C:66:66:0:0%:1E0', 'C:18:18:0:0%:1E0', 'C:26:26:0:0%:1E0', 'C:95:95:0:0%:1E0']
```

Does someone know how the regex can be modified so that it includes optional decimals in the string? Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I need it to include other letters as well, such as the "Y:106:104:2:1.89%:2.4882E-1" part of the string

Comment: Then why not use `s.split()`? What are the pattern requirements (rules)?

Comment: I was definitely making this more complicated than it needs to be. Thank you!